# Can I make a graph between two xhttp variables?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, arduino-esp8266

I tried to make a graph between two variables instead of graphinh time but I couldn't. So I want to know I this is available by the way?

```
    var chartT = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: { renderTo: "chart-temperature" },
      title: { text: "DHT22 Temperature" },
      series: [
        {
          showInLegend: false,
          data: [],
        },
      ],
      plotOptions: {
        line: { animation: false, dataLabels: { enabled: true } },
        series: { color: "#059e8a" },
      },
      xAxis: { type: "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats: { second: "%H:%M:%S" } },
      yAxis: {
        title: { text: "Temperature (Celsius)" },
        //title: { text: 'Temperature (Fahrenheit)' }
      },
      credits: { enabled: false },
    });
    setInterval(function () {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var x = new Date().getTime(),
            y = parseFloat(this.responseText);
          //console.log(this.responseText);
          if (chartT.series[0].data.length > 40) {
            chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true, true);
          } else {
            chartT.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, false, true);
          }
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "/temperature", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }, 30000);

    var chartH = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: { renderTo: "chart-humidity" },
      title: { text: "DHT22 Humidity" },
      series: [
        {
          showInLegend: false,
          data: [],
        },
      ],
      plotOptions: {
        line: { animation: false, dataLabels: { enabled: true } },
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { second: "%H:%M:%S" },
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: { text: "Humidity (%)" },
      },
      credits: { enabled: false },
    });
    setInterval(function () {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          var x = new Date().getTime(),
            y = parseFloat(this.responseText);
          //console.log(this.responseText);
          if (chartH.series[0].data.length > 40) {
            chartH.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true, true);
          } else {
            chartH.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, false, true);
          }
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "/humidity", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }, 30000);
```

I wanted to make a graph between humidity on y axis and temperature on x axis. I tried changing the x variable ,of the humidity chart, to be like the y variable ,of the temperature chart, but the chart of the humidity didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to synchronize the received data from the two API requests. Here's a solution that records partial data (either temperature or humidity) - `pending` array and identifies corresponding requests by registering the time of the requested - `tRequest`.

This may be a starting point for your more elaborate solution. Please let me know if this is not exactly what you wanted.

The data is simulated (random points) as I don't have access to your API, but there are real XMLHttpRequests (to highcharts on cdn).

The same in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8u23qLv/)

```js
var chartT = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { renderTo: "chart-temperature" },
    title: { text: "DHT22 Temperature" },
    series: [
        {
            showInLegend: false,
            data: [],
        },
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        line: { animation: false, dataLabels: { enabled: true } },
        series: { color: "#059e8a" },
    },
    xAxis: { type: "datetime", dateTimeLabelFormats: { second: "%H:%M:%S" } },
    yAxis: {
        title: { text: "Temperature (Celsius)" },
        //title: { text: 'Temperature (Fahrenheit)' }
    },
    credits: { enabled: false },
});

var chartH = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { renderTo: "chart-humidity" },
    title: { text: "DHT22 Humidity" },
    series: [
        {
            showInLegend: false,
            data: [],
        },
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        line: { animation: false, dataLabels: { enabled: true } },
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { second: "%H:%M:%S" },
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: { text: "Humidity (%)" },
    },
    credits: { enabled: false },
});

var chartTH = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: { renderTo: "chart-temperature-humidity", type: "scatter" },
    title: { text: "DHT22 Humidity vs Temperature" },
    series: [
        {
            showInLegend: false,
            data: [],
        },
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        //line: { animation: false, dataLabels: { enabled: true } },
        scatter: {marker: {fillColor: '#ce4a05'}}
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: { text: "Temperature (Celsius)" },
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: { text: "Humidity (%)" },
    },
    credits: { enabled: false },
});


function requestTemperature(whenReceived) { // whenReceived is a handler to be called when a data point was received
    var tRequest = new Date().getTime();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var x = new Date().getTime(),
                y = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)/4;//parseFloat(this.responseText);
            whenReceived(x, y, tRequest);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.2/highcharts.js", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function requestHumidity(whenReceived) {
    var tRequest = new Date().getTime();
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var x = new Date().getTime(),
                y = Math.floor(100+Math.random()*250)/4;//parseFloat(this.responseText);
            whenReceived(x, y, tRequest);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.2/highcharts.js", true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function addToChart(chart, [x, y]){
    if (chart.series[0].data.length > 40) {
        chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true, true);
    } else {
        chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, false, true);
    }
}

var pending = []; // pending array will contain values received for only one of the variables
function afterTemperatureReceived(x, y, tRequest){
    addToChart(chartT, [x, y]);
    var humidityReceived = pending.findIndex(o => Math.abs(o.tRequest - tRequest) < 100);
    if(humidityReceived >= 0){ // a humidity value was received with a call time very close to this
        var H = pending.splice(humidityReceived, 1)[0].H; // delete from pending and retain H value
        addToChart(chartTH, [y, H]); // current y is temp, the first (x) coordinate of chartTH
    }
    else{ // humidity not yet received
        // add temperature to pending, waiting for its  humidity to be received
        pending.push({T: y, tRequest});
    }
}

function afterHumidityReceived(x, y, tRequest){
    addToChart(chartH, [x, y]);
    var temperatureReceived = pending.findIndex(o => Math.abs(o.tRequest - tRequest) < 100);
    if(temperatureReceived >= 0){ // a temperature value was received with a call time very close to this
        var T = pending.splice(temperatureReceived, 1)[0].T; // delete from pending and retain T value
        addToChart(chartTH, [T, y]); // current y is humidity, the second (y) coordinate of  chartTH
    }
    else{ // temperature not yet received
        // add humidity to pending, waiting for its  humidity to be received
        pending.push({H: y, tRequest});
    }
}

function mainTick(){
    requestTemperature(afterTemperatureReceived);
    requestHumidity(afterHumidityReceived);
}

mainTick();
setInterval(mainTick, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.2/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="chart-temperature" style="height:20vh;min-height:350px"></div>
<div id="chart-humidity" style="height:20vh;min-height:350px"></div>
<div id="chart-temperature-humidity" style="height:20vh;min-height:350px"></div>
```